# How to write more efficient linq to entities query using EF6

Tags: performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I have an one-to-many relation in my entities:

```
public class Header
{
   public Header()
   {
       Items = new List<Item>
   }
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Item> Items {get; set;}
   // other properties
}

public class Item
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public virtual Header Header { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; } 
   public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; } 
   public int Weight { get; set; } 
}
```

I want to load `Header` and some of its `Items`, so I wrote this linq to entity query(EF6):

```
using(var ctx = new MyContext())
{
   var result = ctx.Headers.Where(someConditions)
      .AsNoTracking()   
      .Select(header => new {
         HeaderId = header.Id,
         //fetch other header properties here
         LastItemCreationDate = header.Items.OrderByDescending(item => item.CreationDate)
                                            .Select(item => item.Title)
                                            .FirstOrDefault(),
         LastItemTitle = header.Items.OrderByDescending(item => item.CreationDate)
                                            .Select(item => item.CreationDate)
                                            .FirstOrDefault(),
         LastItemWeight = header.Items.OrderByDescending(item => item.CreationDate)
                                            .Select(item => item.Weight)
                                            .FirstOrDefault()
      }).ToList();
}
```

This query generate a sql script with 3 times join `Header` and `Item` tables, is there any more efficent way to write this query to join `Header` and `Item` tables one time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `Select`, you don't need `AsNoTracking` since the resulting query will not load any entities. The key performance impacts in your case would be indexes in the Header table suitability for your `Where` clause, then also whether there is a Descending Index available on the CreationDate in the Items table.

Another improvement would be to alter the projection slightly:

```
var result = ctx.Headers.Where(someConditions)
  .Select(header => new {
     HeaderId = header.Id,
     LatestItem = header.Items
         .OrderByDescending(item => item.CreatedDate)
         .Select(item => new 
         {
            Title = item.Title,
            CreationDate = item.CreationDate,
            Weight = item.Weight
         }).FirstOrDefault()
  }).ToList();
```

This will change the resulting anonymous type structure a bit, but should result in a nicer, single join.

You will get a result.HeaderId, then a null-able result.LastestItem containing the latest item's properties. So `result.LatestItem?.Title` instead of `result.Title`.